# Shortcut for clearing a column on Tweetdeck

Tags: twitter, keyboard-shortcuts, javascript, tweetdeck

I like to keep the queue of my tweetdeck columns clear, so I can quickly see what's new. So I clear each column after I've read it off. But it always takes three clicks on each column to clear it (1. open column settings, 2. clear, 3. close column settings).

So it would be extremely handy, if there would be a better way:

- Is there a keyboard shortcut to clear a selected column?
- Is there a short to clear the whole tweetdeck (that'd also be nice!)?
- Or is there any other way to clear a column (the deck) with less than three clicks?

## Update

It's not about a temporary clearing of the column (e.g. a JavaScript workaround where you `empty()` the column, but when you reload the page the column is filled again). The workaround shall permanently remove the items as if clicked on "Clear".

Answer (score 2):

I write a user script for clear Tweetdeck Tweet https://openuserjs.org/scripts/b1nj/TweetDeck_Clear

for use this script you must install an extension [specific to your browser](https://openuserjs.org/about/Userscript-Beginners-HOWTO).